# sort numbers from highest to lowest in javascript without using sort()

Tags: javascript

```js
const num = 12345

for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
  const j = i + 1
  if (num.charAt(i) < num.charAt(j)) {

    num.replace(i, j)
  }
}

console.log(num)
```

I'm trying to make a `function` that replace sort() method by javascript.

I want to sort my number from highest to lowest inside the variable `num`  and return it after change.
Here I'm using `for loop` with `j` so I'll be able to compare the indexes and change `num` but something wrong what do I miss?

I would love to keep it simple for my understanding..
thanks to the helpers!

Comment: 'but something wrong'... and what is wrong?

Comment: `num.length` returns `undefined`

Comment: You treat `num` like a `string` but it is a `number`. Use `const num = "1234"`

Comment: Why? what is wrong with `sort`? Is just an excercise, or does it have a serious use case?

Comment: First of all, yes, something does not working so something wrong and I'm learning and looking for help. so it's fine.
Secondly, it's clear why i do not want to use sort () that's all the deal of learning. (:

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: @BitterPirate constants can not be changed after declaration; charAt expects to look in string not in number. Don't know if that algorithm will actually work. Can you provide more input and output data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let num = 32145; // you can't change constants after declaration so we are using variables
num = num.toString(); // convert number to string
num = num.split(''); // split the number to array
//Bubble Sort starts here
var len = num.length;
for (var i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        if (num[j - 1] > num[j]) {
            var temp = num[j - 1];
            num[j - 1] = num[j];
            num[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
//Bubble Sort ends here
num = num.join(''); //convert array to string
num = parseInt(num); //convert string to number
console.log(num);
```

> You can read more about these functions below
>
> 1. [Number to string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/toString)
> 2. [String split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
> 3. [Array join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
> 4. [bubble sort function](https://khan4019.github.io/front-end-Interview-Questions/sort.html)
> 5. [ParseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, for the example and explanations, now it's clearer .. Thank you very much angel.bonev!

Comment: @BitterPirate you're welcome I've added some extra links if you want to learn more about these functions

Comment: @BitterPirate @angel.bonev One small edition I'd make is to simply print `num.join()`. The reason why is because if we have `0` somewhere in `num`, it'll get put to the start and `parseInt()` ignores numbers that have `0` at the start because numbers don't start with `0`! ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the working example without javascript sort:**

```js
let num = "12345"
 
for (let j = 0; j < num.length - 1; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < num.length - 1; i++) {
      if (num[i] < num[i + 1]) {
        let temp = num[i + 1];
        num = num.replace(num[i+1], num[i]);
        num = num.replace(num[i], temp);
      }; 
    }; 
};
 
console.log(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this sorting like this It's much simpler

```
const test = "124536"
const result = test.split('').sort().join('');
```

```js
const test = "124536"

const result = test.split('').sort().join('');

console.log(result)
```

Comment: OP specifically said they didn't want to use `.sort()`

Comment: thank jay, freefaller rights, without using sort but thank anyway..

Answer (score 0):

You can hold your numbers in an array if you want.

```js
    var numbers= [1,2,3,4,5];
    for(i=0;i<numbers.length-1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<numbers.length-i-1;j++){
            if(numbers[j]<numbers[j+1]){
                var temp = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = numbers[j+1];
                numbers[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason why your code didn't work**

You thought that `num.replace(...)` would actually change `num`. In JavaScript, primitive data-types (of which numbers are one of) cannot be changed. What `num.replace(...)` actually does is return a *completely new string* that is identical to `num` - except, of course, with the replacement.

```js
function showLowestToHighest(num) {
    let numAsString = num.toString();
    let rawNumArray = [];
    for (const character of numAsString) {
        rawNumArray.push(Number.parseInt(character));
    }
    let sortedNumArray = [];

    for (let index = 0; index < numAsString.length; index++) {
        let smallestNum = Math.min(...rawNumArray);
        sortedNumArray.push(smallestNum);
        let smallestNumIndex = rawNumArray.indexOf(smallestNum);
        rawNumArray.splice(smallestNumIndex, 1);
    }
    console.log(sortedNumArray.join(''));
}

showLowestToHighest(894560);
```

**How this function works**

We establish `rawNumArray` - an array of the digits we're looking at. We then remove the smallest digit from `rawNumArray` and place it at the end of `sortedNumArray`, doing this until `rawNumArray` is empty. Finally, we log out the contents of `sortedNumArray` - as a string.

Weakness: if the number if larger then `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` it won't work.